# D3.js force. custom color

Tags: d3.js, colors

I have edges, some of them have the label "instance_of" connection.
How to color nodes which have "instance of" connection in one color?
Lets say I have node A and B (with the connection) and I want to color it blue
and nodes X and Y (with the connection) color it white?
For now I've made this code in color function.

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(dataArray.nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr({"r": 15})
            .style("fill", function (d, i) { //change node color
                if (dataArray.edges[i].label == 'instance_of'){
                    return colors(i);
                }
            })
            .call(force.drag)
```

UPDATE:
I have:

```
 "nodes": [ 
{ "name": "0"},
{ "name": "1" },
{ "name": "2"  },
{ "name": "3" }],
"edges":[{ "source": 0, "target": 3, "label" : "instance_of" },
{ "source": 1, "target": 2, label" : "instance_of" },
{ "source": 0, "target": 1, "label" : "class_of },]
```

I want to color node[0] and node[3] in one color, because they have a link called 'instance_of', the same to do with node[1] and node[2].

I'm stuck a bit whit it. What function should I write?

Comment: I believe it will be better if you put a fiddle for this..and you example is aloso not correct  `nodes X and Y (with the connection)` and `node A and B (with the connection) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the color selector on the wrong function or selection. Your data has "label" on the links, so there is where you make a question:

```
"is this link 'instance_of'
       then color source and target circles with blue
  else make it red"
```

to do that you first need create the source and target circles:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
```

then, create links:

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
```

on the link function you have available the information about "label"

```
  .style("fill", function (d, i) {
      if (d.label == 'instance_of'){
        console.log("#node_"+d.source.name, "blue");
        d3.select("#node_"+d.source.name).style("fill", "blue");
        d3.select("#node_"+d.target.name).style("fill", "blue");
      } else {
        console.log("#node_"+d.source.name, "red");
        d3.select("#node_"+d.source.name).style("fill", "red");
        d3.select("#node_"+d.target.name).style("fill", "red");
      }
```

You are NOT styling the link, with the select you are pointing to **source** and **target** circles.

[Here's a working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/1O8Rxaoru4TEhAhegdZh?p=preview)